# Admin password on Arris Surfboard SVG2482AC does not work even after reset

Tags: cable-modem

From the title .. I'm not sure where to go with this problem.. I put in the default user of admin and the password that is printed on the modem.

[image]

I get this:

[image]

What can be done now ?

Comment: Did you purchase the device or has your ISO provided this device?

Comment: @Ramhound I think you meant to write ISP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer - maybe obvious to many of you - was not for me.  I tried to reset the device three times. The last time did "take". The difference:  I depressed the reset button a full 30+ seconds.   Waiting "a while" was not enough.